# SwiftUI/WatchOS - Picker inside a ScrollView does not work as expected

Tags: swiftui, watchos

**What I am trying to build**

Apple Watch app(written in SwiftUI, targeting watchOS 7 or higher, built with Xcode 14.1)

**The Problem**

Picker placed inside a ScrollView on an apple watch device does not work as expected

I want to find out how to get the Picker to work as expected, stated below.

**Expected behavior**

On an iOS simulator, a Picker inside a ScrollView works as expected.

- If I try scroll interaction on the Picker area, the ScrollView part doesn’t get scrolled and only the Picker gets scrolled.

whereas on the watch simulator Example,

- If I try to scroll the Picker by touching the Picker area, the whole ScrollView reacts and moves up and down. And I am not able to control the Picker properly.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
ScrollView {
    //..other view elements..
    
    Picker(selection: $currentDay) {
        ForEach(weekDays, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    } label: {
        Text("")
    }
    .frame(width: 148,height: 50)
    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    
   //..other view elements..
}//: ScrollView
```

**Things I have tried**

- putting the Picker inside a VStack/ZStack/HStack
- giving the Picker fixed frame values / giving other elements inside the ScrollView fixed frame values